# Question about UpgradeSchema and UpgradeData files

Tags: magento2, install-script, setup-script, upgrade-script

Sorry, I'm new in using Magento 2.

In my `UpgradeSchema.php` I would like to add a column to my table and in my `UpgradeData.php`

I would like to add new records to the table.

In both the file i have this if statement...

```
if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', "<")) {
    //do something
}
```

My ask is :

Who `$context->getVersion()` and `1.0.1` are ?

Does `$context->getVersion()` match with the `setup_version` in my `module.xml` file ?

Answer (score 1):

The `$context->getVersion()` is the number that is located in the setup_module table, in the schema_version column, of the row that corresponds to your module.

Therefore, the comparison `if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', "<")) {` looks to see if the value in the DB is smaller than 1.0.1, if yes, it runs the upgrade code.

Comment: But..what happens if i don't set the schema_version in my module.xml file?

Comment: You have to set the setup_version in your module.xml, otherwise, Magento will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

In your database, `setup_module` table you'll find something like this :

```
+-------------------+----------------+--------------+
| module            | schema_version | data_version |
+-------------------+----------------+--------------+
| Yourmodule_Name   | 1.0.1          | 1.0.1        |
+-------------------+----------------+--------------+
```

In your module : `app/code/Yourmodule/Name/etc/module.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Yourmodule_Name" setup_version="1.0.1"/>
</config>
```

In your module : `app/code/Yourmodule/Name/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php`

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.O.1', '<')) {
    //script code here
}
```

1. First you should have `setup_version` in `module.xml`, without you will have en Exception error something like this:

   > [Exception]
   >   Attribute 'setup_version' is missing for module 'Yourmodule_Name'.
2. `$context->getVersion()` refers to this `setup_version`, This means that the script are only run when the `setup_version` is equal here in our exemple to `1.0.1`
3. After changing the module version exemple from `setup_version="1.0.1"` to `setup_version="1.0.2"`, you need to run this command : `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` so this this command update the `schema_version | data_version` version  from `1.0.1 | 1.0.1` to `1.0.2 | 1.0.2`, otherwise without this command, you'll have an `report` Error something like this :

   > Please upgrade your database: Run \"bin/magento setup:upgrade\"

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The two extant answers are correct but slightly incomplete.

To be clear, the number returned by `$context->getVersion()` is the version number that is found **before** the number is increased to whatever version number is now configured in `etc/module.xml`.